# How can I declare a map parameter which accept any type of value in golang?

Tags: go, generics

For your convenience: [go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/C3zWbjlgxy5)

I has a function which does not care the value type of a map parameter, so
I declare it as this:

`func foo(generalMap map[string]interface{}) {}`

But when I call it with a specified map like this:

```
myMap := make(map[string]Bar)
foo(myMap)
```

Then the compiler error comes out:
`cannot use myMap (type map[string]Bar) as type map[string]interface {} in argument to foo`

Comment: Soon (in Go 1.18), you'll be able to write such a generic function: `func foo[V any](generalMap map[string]V) { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You CANNOT do that. `map[string]interface{}` and `map[string]Bar` are two different types. You have to build a `map[string]interface{}` with the `map[string]Bar` manually.

```
mapAny := make(map[string]interface{})
for key, val := range myMap {
    mapAny[key] = val
}
foo(mapAny)
```

What you need is template in C++, however, Golang doesn't have template support.

Comment: Hello from the future, It's ~March 2022, and we now have go-1.18. To anybody reading this, you may now use type aliases, like this: `map[string]any`. Where `any` is a type alias for `interface{}`. Have a great day!